# Automate the Boring Stuff With Python, Chapter 4 Exercise

Tags: python, list

I'm newbie and doing Al Sweigar's book at the moment. In chapter 4's exercise, he asks the following,

Say you have a list of lists where each value in the inner lists is a one-character string, like this:

```
 grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
         ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
         ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
         ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
         ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
```

You can think of grid[x][y] as being the character at the x- and y-coordinates of a “picture” drawn
     with text characters. The (0, 0) origin will be in the upper-left
     corner, the x-coordinates increase going right, and w the
     y-coordinates increase going down. Copy the previous grid value, and
     write code that uses it to print the image.

```
..OO.OO.. 
.OOOOOOO. 
.OOOOOOO. 
..OOOOO.. 
...OOO... 
....O....
```

So I have written the code and it does what he asks for but I think its very poorly written and I wanted to ask you how can I improve it. My code,

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

newString = ''

for i in range(len(grid)):
    newString += str(grid[i][0])

newString1 = '\n'
for i in range(len(grid)):
    newString1 += str(grid[i][1])

newString2 = '\n'
for i in range(len(grid)):
    newString2 += str(grid[i][2])

newString3 = '\n'
for i in range(len(grid)):
    newString3 += str(grid[i][3])

newString4 = '\n'
for i in range(len(grid)):
    newString4 += str(grid[i][4])

newString5 = '\n'
for i in range(len(grid)):
    newString5 += str(grid[i][5])

print(newString+newString1+newString2+newString3+newString4+newString5)
```

Output of program:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Comment: If your code works, this might be better suited to CodeReview.SE. Note that `''.join((foo, bar))` is neater than `foo + bar`, and handles an arbitrary number of inputs, though (also, you can do the whole thing with `'\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*grid)))`)

Comment: as soon as you start writing the same code over and over again with variable named `newString1`, `newString2`,..., you know you need something else. (A loop, for example)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
>>> print('\n'.join(map(''.join, zip(*grid))))
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

The `zip(*grid)` effectively transposes the matrix (flip it on the main diagonal), then each row is joined into one string, then the rows are joined with newlines so the whole thing can be printed at once.

Answer (score 24):

I'm a newbie too - Using only what the book had covered, and keeping in mind the loop within a loop hint, this is my answer:

```
for j in range(len(grid[0])):
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[i][j],end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: You don't need the `''` in the final print statement.

Comment: I appreciate sticking to what the book had taught so far!

Comment: This is exactly what I did but I am still trying to figure out how to do this without explicitly specifying grid[0]. I mean, what if the lists varied in length? How do you solve that? There has to be a way to define grid[0] without using a literal value.

Comment: I did this but used  constant literals instead of len().

Answer (score 5):

One way you can approach the problem (given the hint in the book), is to define rows and columns. The given list has 9 rows (elements of the list) and 6 columns (length of each element).

Clearly then the problem becomes -

a) Print all the column values for row 1
b) Print all the column values for row 2
... and so on

This approach can be 'standardized' once we measure the number of rows and columns to be printed beforehand

The following program illustrates one way of doing this -

```
# This program illustrates the character picture grid


grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

rows = len(grid) # Number of elements in the list
cols = len(grid[0]) # Number of elements in every single element in the list

for j in range(cols):
    for i in range(rows):
        print(grid[i][j], end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 4):

I have another simple solution, very similar to other solutions using only for loops.  But one thing I seem to did different is that I used two augmented operators, one inside the inside-loop, one outside of it. I thought it would be useful after figuring out what we are asked for.

```
print(grid[0][0],
      grid[1][0],
      grid[2][0],
      grid[3][0],
      grid[4][0],
      grid[5][0],
      grid[6][0],
      grid[7][0],
      grid[8][0])
```

### Output of Print Statement:

> . . O O . O O . .

As you can see, it's the first line of the heart grid. We need to **count from *0* to *len(grid[0])***, -that's the number of items in the first list, you can just type 6 as well. So, all I needed is two operators counting inside each other. The empty print statement is for line-breaks. If we don't use it, it prints out either all characters on the same line, or each character on each line.

### Solution:

```
def printer(grid):
    for m in range(len(grid[0])):
        print()
        for n in range(len(grid)):
            print (grid[n][m],end="")
            n+=1        
    m+=1
```

### Output:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Answer (score 4):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
       ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
       ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
       ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

def gridOutput(grid):
    for s in range(len(grid[0])):
        print()
        for i in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[i][s],end='')
gridOutput(grid)
```

Only used the info I learned in the earlier chapters. I do appreciate reading through more advanced techniques for the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

The author says to use a loop in a loop. Here is my answer:

```
def reformat(myList):
    for i in range(0,len(myList[0])):
        myStr = ''
        for j in range(0,(len(myList))):
            myStr += myList[j][i]           
        print(myStr)
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
    grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

    for i in range(len(grid[0])):
        print()
        for j in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[j][i], end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def heart():
    #Set your range to the length of the first list in grid.
    for y in range(len(grid[0])):
        #This print('') will break every printed line once the second for loop completes below.
        print('')
        #Set your second for loop to the length of the number of lists within grid.
        for x in range(len(grid)):
            #Add an end keyword arg to allow for consecutive str prints without new lines.
            print(grid[x][y],end='')
heart()
```

> 

```
def heart():
    for y in range(len(grid[0])):
    print('')
        for x in range(len(grid)):
             print(grid[x][y],end='')
heart()
```

^ code without the comments.

Think of the pattern Al is asking for. [0][0],[0][1],[0][2]...[8][0],[8][1],[8][2]. So you basically want the first for to indicate which list to pull data from and then a for within that to choose the index to print. The end keyword arg is crucial as well.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way:

```
for i in range(len(grid[1])):
    for row in grid:
        print (row[i], end='')
    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice solutions! I'm not nearly that comfortable using map(). Regarding the exercise I set myself a challenge to flip the grid 90-degrees.

First it makes a grid that has the same number of lists as the length of single list in the original grid (to get the x-axis). Then it appends the first (or n-th) elements of each list of the original grid to the first (or n-th) list of the new grid and prints out each line of the new grid.

It could be done in fewer lines of code, but here it is:

```
def character_picture_grid(x):
"""The character_picture _grid print a grid list
with list(9 x 6) and rotates it 90-degrees."""

# Flip the grid.
newGrid = [[] for i in range(len(x[0]))]
for i in range(len(newGrid)):
    for a in range(len(x)):
        newGrid[i].append(x[a][i])

# Print the grid
for i in newGrid:
    print(i)
```

EDIT: Grammar.

Answer (score 0):

Its important to keep in mind that the idea of the exercise is to resolve it with what you´ve learn till this chapter, so one way using loop in a loop:

```
def grilla(x):
    for y in range(6):
        print()
        for i in range(len(x)):
            print(x[i][y], end='')
grilla(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys im am new to python, here is my answer.

```
for i in range(len(grid[1])):
 print(' ')
 for z in range(len(grid)):
  print(grid[z][i], end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

I also took the hint from the author to use the loop within a loop.  So I actually just used a combination of a while and for loop. Here is my code:

```
#First I copied the grid as the author instructs

grid = [['.','.','.','.','.','.'],
       ['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
       ['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
       ['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
       ['.','0','0','0','0','0'],
       ['0','0','0','0','0','.'],
       ['0','0','0','0','.','.'],
       ['.','0','0','.','.','.'],
       ['.','.','.','.','.','.']]

# I set two global variables x and y. I will use x to iterate through 
# the while loop and y to increment the index in the inner list
x = 0
y = 0

# set the condition for the while loop to limit it to the length of the list
# and also to limit it to the length of the inner list which doesn't exceed index 5 

while x < len(grid) and y <= 5:
   for item in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[item][y], end='')

    y += 1 # increment y after iteration of a for loop 
    print('') # print blank line
    x += 1 # increment x after iteration of for loop go through for loop again
```

Output

```
..00.00..
.0000000.
.0000000.
..00000..
...000...
....0....
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it even like this

```
for i in range(len(grid[])):
    for j in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[j][i],end = " ")

    print()
```

Answer (score 0):

My try, also by combining for and while. Not as pretty as previous answers but still good enough for me.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]
x=0 #counter
y=0 #counter

for y in range(len(grid[x])): #for each y in sublists
    new_str=""                  #create temporary new string to house the sublists
    while x <= len(grid)-1:     #for each x in list
        new_str += grid[x][y]   
        x+=1                    #add every x in a string while keeping y steady
    print(new_str)              #print string of x's while y steady
    x=0                         #set x to 0 in order to start again on next iteration of y
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for j in range(len(grid[:6])):
  # print(grid[0][j]) 
    for i in range(len(grid)):
        print(grid[i][j], end='')
    print()
```

The commented out part printed a lone dot on the first line. The O figure itself was correct, some other dots were missing on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

I am newbie too, and I used only what the book has covered. This is my code.

```
for i in range(len(grid[0])):
               for j in range(len(grid)):
                   if j == (len(grid)-1):
                       print(grid[j][i])
                   else:
                       print(grid[j][i], end='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer:

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

for i in range(len(grid[0])):
    col=[col[i] for col in grid]
    print(*col, sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

Also new to python, my answer below, and it works.

```
for i in range(0,6,1):
    for j in range(0,8,1):     
        print(grid[j][i], end='')
    print('')
```

Comment: You could use `len()` in the range functions. Also the `''` in your final print statement is redundant, `print()` will do.

Comment: If you reverse the inner loop, and read from the last list first, you get a 90 degree rotation of the item and not a rotation and transposition. Put a different character in grid[0][0] and watch what happens. That character's position in the image doesn't move. The whole thing ends up being a mirror image.

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
    ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
    ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
    ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

def love_grid(name):

    xyz = int(len(list(name)) - 1)

    for a in range(0, len(list(name))):

        print(name[a][0], end="")
        if a == xyz:
            print()
            break

    for a in range(0, len(list(name))):

        print(name[a][1], end="")
        if a == xyz:
           print()
           break

    for a in range(0, len(list(name))):

        print(name[a][2], end="")
        if a == xyz:
            print()
            break

   for a in range(0, len(list(name))):

        print(name[a][3], end="")
        if a == xyz:
            print()
            break

   for a in range(0, len(list(name))):

        print(name[a][4], end="")
        if a == xyz:
           print()
           break

   for a in range(0, len(list(name))):

       print(name[a][5], end="")
        if a == xyz:
           print()
           break



love_grid(grid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def grid(l):
    for i in range(len(l)):
        print('')

        for j in range(len(l[i])):
            s=l[j][i]
            print(s,end='')
```

This takes care of the commas too.

Comment: The `''` in your blank/newline print statement is redundant: `print()` will do.

Also, why not just print `l([j][i]` rather than assigning that value to `s` and then printing `s`?

Answer (score 0):

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]

count = 0
while count < len(grid):
    print()
    try:
        for x in range(len(grid)):
            print(grid[x][count], end='')
    except IndexError:
        break

    count += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I just started reading the book and here is what I came up with, seems pretty simple.

```
grid = [['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.'],
        ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', '.'],
        ['.', 'O', 'O', '.', '.', '.'],
        ['.', '.', '.', '.', '.', '.']]


def final(grid_solve, count):
    empty = ""
    for i in grid_solve:
        empty += i[count]

    return empty


total = 0

while total != len(grid[0]):
    print(final(grid, total))
    total += 1
```

Output:

```
..OO.OO..
.OOOOOOO.
.OOOOOOO.
..OOOOO..
...OOO...
....O....
```

Answer (score -1):

```
for x in range (0,6):
    for y in range (0,9):
        print (grid[y][x], end='')
    print ('')
```

Answer (score -2):

```
b=len(grid)  
for y in range(b-3):  
    print('\n')  
    for x in range(b):  
        print(grid[x][y], end=' ')
```